# What is a preferred way of closing a third-application thread without waiting for it to complete?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am currently running the JAR that I cannot change, and sometimes it simply gets stuck for no good reason. I have tried finding the ways to interrupt the thread, stop the thread, etceteras, but no luck.

Each solution offered was about doing the complete exit or waiting for a thread to complete.

What I want to do is to simply close the thread, exactly when the timeout completes, and carry on with the program.

What I do not want to do is use the while loop with a timeout, java.util.concurrent.Future, System.exit, and make a Thread.interrupt call.

None of these will help!

Comment: If you want a "complete solution" please ask a complete question!

Comment: Do you have access ot the thread at all?  If so, can you just set its priority to the lowest possible and just, well, forget about it?

Comment: I mean, well, if it's stuck, not using anything, why worry?  Just forget it ever existed.  If it's not doing anything, it's stack etc. will eventually just get paged out and it may as well not exist.  Whatever object manages it - just make another one.

Comment: No, because I may encounter the same issue too often, and eventually, there will be an overflow.

Comment: OK, well, do you pass anything into it that you can change/corrupt/signal/whatever so as to force an exception to be raised?

Comment: Thanks for the quick accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can't really solve this!

What I mean is: even if you would manage to kill "your" thread that you used to trigger the 3rd party code - you have **no** way of killing threads or processes created by the code you are invoking.

If you want to be absolutely sure to **kill** all and anything, you might have to look into rather complex solutions like:

- instead of just using a thread, you create a new **process** with a new JVM B
- in that JVM B,  you can call that library
- but of course, that requires that you put additional code around; so that "your" code in JVM A can talk to "your" code in JVM B
- And now you might be able to tear down that process, and all artifacts belonging to it. Maybe.

And seriously: to be really really sure that the 3rd party library didn't kick of anything that you can't stop; you might even have to run that JVM inside some kind of container (for example a docker instance). That you could tear down and be sure that *everything* is gone.

Long story short: I think there is no way to **absolutely** control the threads created in a thread. If you need that level of control, you need to look into "outsourcing" those calls.

Comment: Liking this answer

Comment: As answered, the only way is to do the shell scripting when the program completely stops, so another instance of it is initiated. It would be nice to do the main inside the main, but then, the JVM would get stuck with the same issue that you mentioned. THANK YOU FOR YOUR ANSWER, and don't forget to upvote the question ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can't forcibly stop a thread in mid-execution.  The [`Thread.destroy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#destroy--) method *would* have done that, but it was never implemented, and its documentation explains why it would be unsafe to use even if it worked.

There are some other deprecated methods like [`Thread.stop()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--) and [`Thread.suspend()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend--) which may actually work, but they're also unsafe to use; again, their documentation explains why.

Telling the thread that it should terminate itself, and then waiting for it to do so, is the only safe way to stop a thread.

---

As an workaround, you could run your task in an entirely separate [process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), so that you can [destroy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#destroy--) it when you want it to stop.  That *is* safe, since processes are isolated from each other and destroying the child process can't leave the parent process in an unstable state.

Interacting with a separate process is more difficult, though, since you can't share variables between processes like you can with threads.  You'd need to send messages through the process's input and output streams.

Comment: I see, so it is the shell scripting + System.exit(0); that will solve it

Comment: You don't need a shell script for the child process; you can just run another JVM directly (but you can use a script if you prefer).  And `System.exit` is for making a program terminate *itself*, which isn't the problem you're having.  To make the main program stop its child process, you'd use `Process.destroy`.

Comment: that would be great if I knew how to initiate Process childProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( ?????? ); properly...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Executor` for this. It allows you to `submit` tasks (e.g. `runnable`) and executes those tasks parallely. Also, once you call `shutdown()`, it lets you configure the timeout and kills all the workers if they are not finished by that time. An example would look like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
executor.execute(() -> {
//logic to call the method of third party jar
});
//Other business logic
executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
executor.shutdownNow();
```

`TimeUnit` is an enum, with values like `SECONDS`, `HOURS`, `MINUTES` etc ([here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) javadoc) so you can configure different time units. A couple of points:

- Once `shutdownNow` is called, no new tasks will be accepted (i.e. you can't call `execute` or `submit`) and existing tasks will be stopped. So, we are basically waiting for a minute for tasks to be complete and if it is not complete, we are killing that task.
- `awaitTermination` throws `InterruptedException` (as it interrupts the threads internally if they are not finished) so you will have to wrap it inside `try-catch` block.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)'s javadoc for Executor.

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers the OP's question of how to stop a running process.

Comment: I believe this answer as a whole explains how to start a task in another thread and stop it after the timeout. That's what the OP asked if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but how does the code stop the 3rd party jar though?

Comment: It will stop the thread that invoked a method in third party jar

Comment: I have to beg to differ on this. Maybe my understanding on this is wrong, but as I understand things, `shutdown()` prevents the executor from gaining other tasks, and `awaitTermination` blocks the current thread until the either the tasks are complete or the time is up, but this has no effect on the running of the tasks themselves -- it does not shut them down.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry, missed that point. We need to wait for a min (or so) for the tasks to complete, and if they are not complete, we need to shutdown the executor. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry to keep pestering you, but for example please run this code: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/AZ2Xb5Bk). As you see, the Runnable keeps running to completion

Comment: Edit: if I check for interrupt before the sleep call, then yes this will stop the runnable in my example -- but your code **only works** if the jar file that he's calling is interruptable, if it tests the status of the interrupt flag and responds to this by stopping. If not then your code is not a viable solution.

Comment: And in fact the OP has already stated that calling interrupt on the thread does not work.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I tried it and it stops the counter after 5 seconds, once wait is over, I guess this is what the OP wants. Reading the question again, it looks like OP has tried finding ways to interrupt the thread but couldn't do so. So, it looks more likely that he didn't have handle to that thread (or implementation that supported interrupting that thread) and that's why it didn't work out. However, I completely agree with your point, will just wait for OP to confirm what exactly does he need :)